# How to stop loop without break

Tags: c

how do i make the loop to stop if the A[]=-999? ( im not allowed to use break or continue)

```
int A[10];
int i , j , b , x;

for(i=0 ; i<10 ; i++)
{
    if(A[10]!=(-999))
    {
    printf(" Enter the Number %d : ", i+1 );
    scanf("%d", &A[i] );
    }
}
```

Comment: 'exit;' ..............................

Comment: `A` array being not initialized and the last element of the array being `A[9]`, this test case seems to be incomplete. Please update it.

Comment: You could use `goto`, although it's not considered good style in general.

Comment: `A` only has 10 elements, indexed 0 - 9, so `A[10]` references a location off the end of the array.  You're invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: @owacoder `goto` is not "terribly bad style". When being used instead of `break` it's only "slightly bad style".

Comment: There are two ways that program execution may exit a loop: it will exit if the loop condition tests `false`, or if control explicitly branches out of the loop.  The `break` statement achieves the latter; of itself, the `continue` statement achieves neither.  You could use `goto`, but that violates the spirit of the constraint, even if not the letter.

Comment: [Obligatory xkcd warning about using `goto`.](https://xkcd.com/292/)

Comment: Occasionally, `goto` is exactly what you want.  The gyrations needed to avoid using it in C can be much worse than the `goto` itself.

Comment: @immibis - It is terribly bad style if there is already a mechanism in the language to accomplish the same with more clarity. In several cases, `goto` could be used instead of spending half a day refactoring code. In this particular case, `break` should always be preferred.

Comment: @owacoder I bet you're one of those people who uses `while(1) {... if(!shouldRetry()) break; printf("Retrying.");}` instead of `retry: ... if(shouldRetry()) {printf("Retrying."); goto retry;}`

Comment: Hey, what happened to the question? It is completely different from the original one. Please recover it back. Otherwise I will have to do it instead.

Comment: Didn't I *just* see a question like this the other day? It must be homework season again.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't present a practical problem as conditions are artificial.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the extra condition for your `for` loop:

```
for(i=0 ; i<10 && A[10]!=(-999) ; i++) {...}
```

But in any case you better initialize `A[10]` for some known initial value. Also your `A` array doesn't have `A[10]` element. It's indices are spanning fro `0` to `9`.

Comment: Tried it and it still not stoping

Comment: Tried what? How do you assign `A[10]` with `-999`? Perhaps you want to check `A[i]` instead?

Comment: [Per comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34029102/how-to-stop-loop-without-break/34029281?noredirect=1#comment55813867_34029132) Checking `A[i]` does not work as `A[i]` has not yet been assigned.  Checking `A[i-1]` does not work when `i=0`

Comment: @chux Right. `do ..while` would be the best method here.

Answer (score 2):

You can set i=10 which will terminate you loop

```
int A[10];
int i , j , b , x;

for(i=0 ; i<10 ; i++)
{
    if(A[i]!=-999)
    {
       printf(" Enter the Number %d : ", i+1 );
       scanf("%d", &A[i] );
    }
    else if(A[i]==-999)
    {
    i=10;
    }
}
```

Comment: its sounds right but im not sure if if(A[10]!=(-999)) is the right way to set it where do i can read about A[X] kind of vars?

Comment: Or you could even set `i = 9`, as it will be incremented by one before the loop condition is tested.

Comment: `if(A[10]!=(-999)` is undefined behavior as `A[10]` does not exist.

Comment: I corrected the code i posted. You can check it out.

Comment: @ManH No, you haven't...

Answer (score 2):

Simply add an `end` flag.

This code below also breaks the loop on non-numeric input.

```
#include <stdbool.h>

int A[10];
int i , j , b , x;
bool OK_to_continue = true;
for(i=0 ; OK_to_continue && i<10 ; i++) {
  printf(" Enter the Number %d : ", i+1 );

  // If scan fails or value read is the special -999
  if (scanf("%d", &A[i] ) != 1 || A[i] == -999) {
    OK_to_continue = false;
  }
}
```

An alternative to `OK_to_continue = false;` is `i = 9;` or `i = 10;`.  The downside to that is the following code has lost the count of valid elements in `A[]`.

Many solutions exist.  Suggest ones that are easy to understand and reasonably efficient.

Comment: are you sure i can write bool like that?

Comment: @4521245 1235 Yes, if using a C99 or later compiler.  Otherwise just use `int`, 0 and 1

Comment: It is not a complete code, of course...

Comment: @Eugene Sh. Yes, not complete code -  trying to match OP's style.

Comment: @45212451235, in C99 and later, the `bool` data type is declared in `stdbool.h`, which you must include as shown.  Alternatively, you can use `_Bool` without including any header; the two types are equivalent.  `stdbool.h` also defines the constants `true` and `false`, btw; without it you must use 1 and 0 in their place.

Comment: I have edited my question can you take a look please

Comment: @45212451235 Recommend reverting your post and not ask about the new code.  You could post the new problem as another post (with a reference to this one), but changing this question so much after so many have worked on it is not good SO etiquette.